# Div Height Border Issues

Tags: html, css, border

everyone!

I'm having a div height/border issue.  Here's the script I'm working with:

```
    .content
        {
            background-image: url(../../images/logo-04.png);
            background-position: left bottom;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: 30%;
            border-bottom: 0.1em solid #000000;
            border-bottom-left-radius: 1em;
            border-bottom-right-radius: 1em;
            border-top: 0.1em solid #000000;
            display: inline-block;
            width: 100%;
        }

    .content-left
        {
            float: left;
            font-size: 100%;
            text-align: justify;
            width: 74%;
        }

    .content-right
        {
            border-left: 1px solid #000000;
            float: right;
            font-size: 80%;
            height: 100%;
            text-align: right;
            width: 25%;
        }
```

And here's a snippet of the div I'm working with:

```
<div class="container2">
    <!-- Content -->
    <div class="content">
        <div class="content-left">
        </div>
        <div class="content-right">
            <div class="sidelinks">
                <ul>
                    <li><a class="link3" href=""></a></li>
                    <li><a class="link3" href=""></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="social">

<---End--!>
```

The divs above are closed properly in my code (I didn't want to bore anyone with the extra coding).

For some reason, I can't seem to get my left border to extend the length of the content-right div unless I use pixels (height: 500px).  I usually use percentage, but at height: 100%, the border only goes as far as the contents inside the content-right div.

Any suggestions to get my desired effect?

Comment: If you make a demo it would be helpful. I'm wondering if you've contained the floats too.

Answer (score 0):

You're not defining a height for .content, so even with `height:100%` it's only 100% of the parent, content.. Try setting content height to 100% and see if the border goes with it

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me, Esutherland.  That's what I thought at first, but it didn't take.  I tried it again and got the same results, unfortunately.

Comment: Not sure what effect you need to achieve, but perhaps `html, body{height:100%}` would ensure that the parent to .content is also stretching beyond just content size.

Comment: Well, for instance, if you go to this page you'll see a better idea of what I'm talking about: http://www.ragnarok.ws/about.html.

The  border on the left side should go all the way down, but it doesn't.  It goes down if I use px, but not percent..

Comment: add `display:table` to your `<div class="content">`

Comment: Awesome.  That did the trick, Esutherland.  Thanks for the help!  Enjoy the weekend!